# How to scroll to the bottom of an image on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

Hi i am just curious to know the best way to go about being able to scroll to the bottom of an image on hover. The image is in a wrapper with overflow hidden applied to it as its quite long. Ideally a smooth scroll to the bottom is what I am looking for to see the rest of the hidden image.

I have been playing around with jquery trying to get it to work but i have got into a muddle. Not sure if I am on the right track with my code or not really.

Appreciate any help

```js
$('#image-wrap img').on('hover', function() {
  var target = $(this),
    height = target.height(),
    scrollHeight = target.prop('scrollHeight');

  target.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollHeight - height
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#main-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: relative;
}

#image-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#image-wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="box-wrapper">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="image-wrap">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x2000" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use simply CSS3. On hover add transition `transform: translateY(-100%)`, but it's not smart like the jquery solution.

```css
#main-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    transition: all 2000ms ease-out;
}

#box:hover img {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="box-wrapper">
    <div id="box">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/1000/sports/" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand now how you would like to it to be.

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#img-holder').mouseenter(function(){
    var x = $('img').height();
    x = x-400;
    $('img').animate({'position':'absolute','top':'-'+x}, 300);
  });
   $('#img-holder').mouseleave(function(){
     $('img').css({'position':'relative','top':'0'});
   });
});
```

```css
#img-holder{
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  border:2px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img-holder">
  <img src="https://blog.hittail.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2013/01/hidden-value-of-long-tail-seo-1000.png" width="100%">
</div>
```

The idea is making the position of the img absolute and give it a value to display the bottom part.

Here is a working [**DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=79e9c857b463e73b0f491b771a446e79)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I edited the code to a working snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your effort =)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```js
$('#image-wrap img').hover(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#main-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: relative;
}

#image-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#image-wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="box-wrapper">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="image-wrap">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x2000" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Superb +1 for running snippet

Comment: Mate you dont understand that when there is overflow hidden on wrapper div you cannot do scroll function. "The image is in a wrapper with overflow hidden applied to it as its quite long." http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=79e9c857b463e73b0f491b771a446e79 this is the answer.

Comment: @GüneySaramalı, you are right. The OPs question is ambiguous. If you want to scroll to the bottom of the image within the div with hidden overflow than its not possible. If you want to scroll the page to the bottom of the wrapper div itself that would be ok as the outer container has overflow.

Comment: nah it wasnt ambiguous he said "The image is in a wrapper with overflow hidden applied to it as its quite long." I dont know if the question is edited but when i read this was stated

Comment: Well, I guess you are right. Perhaps a solution would be to try to set overflow hidden to an outer div.

Comment: Check out my answer and see my way.

Comment: @GuneySaramali The reason I am looking to try this is because the image will be inside a mockup computer screen image which has a limited outer height of 400px. All i want is for when the computer image is hovered the screen inside it will scroll down so you can view the rest of the image within the screen if that makes sense. Thanks for you input and everyone else, got some good working ideas here. Maybe I didn't explain myself very well

Comment: If we have solved your problem then no matter what. Thank you too.

Answer (score -1):

If the image is hidden, you cannot interact with it. If it is visible, you can use scrollTo() like this.

1. Capture the current scroll position using scrollTop()

   var pos = $('your image container').scrollTop();
2. Grab the height of the image container

   var height = $('your image container').height();
3. Add the two values

   var moveto = pos + height;
4. Autoscroll to the position

   window.scrollTo( 0, moveto );

Answer (score -2):

So I guess you want to scroll the whole page (kinda like using your mouse-wheel)?

You could do something like this:

```
$('#image-wrap img').on('hover', function() {
  var target = $(this),
    height = target.height(),
    scrollHeight = target.offset().top;

    $('body,html').animate({
         scrollTop:scrollHeight+height-500
    },500);
});
```

This would then scroll the page, so the last 500px of the image are visible. If that doesn't solve your problem, an example with the whole page would be helpful.

Comment: He is not trying to use scroll function. The wrapper div has overflow hidden which mean you cannot do scroll function on it. check this http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=79e9c857b463e73b0f491b771a446e79